# How to load more than 1500 products in a page without pageloading?

Tags: javascript, php, html, .net

I am adding SEO for Category Page which has more than 1500 products in a category I don't want to put pagination Or any kind of ajax which will load few products and then on page scroll load the next products IS there any way to load all product without letting the user know that page Is loading?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Your page will probably have several megabytes of data of HTML code alone.

Comment: I am trying with lazy loading but I want google to read all data in my category page AND simultaneously I want my user not to feel like the page is continuously loading So is there any way please help me out with this..!!

Answer (score 1):

Please be careful, you will have a lot of performance penalties when loading 1500 products on a single request and that will affect your customer's browser (frozen, crashed, etc).

If it's for SEO only I think you can load them at once but using CSS to hide most of them from the view (only show 20-40 products for example). It's still available in HTML code but the client doesn't see them and performance still good.

Whenever they want to see more products, just toggle some CSS classes to show them but using lazy load or pagination to *fake* the loading.

Comment: This way i have tried but in Google Console I am not getting the entire product I want google to read all the data. In my category page.

Comment: how do you implement the idea? I mean what kind of CSS style that you applied?